Why is the check50 indicating that the min found is incorrect when it is correct on runoff algorithm?
I am doing the runoff election algorithm form the CS50 course. The check50 is saying that the program is working properly but it is saying that the function find min is not returning the correct min when all the candidates are tied. I tested it myself with 3 candidates and 3 voters each one voting in an different candidate, I printed the min to check and it was 1 as it should be and the program indicated a tie properly.
This is the feedback from check 50:
:) runoff.c exists
:) runoff compiles
:) vote returns true when given name of candidate
:) vote returns false when given name of invalid candidate
:) vote correctly sets first preference for first voter
:) vote correctly sets third preference for second voter
:) vote correctly sets all preferences for voter
:) tabulate counts votes when all candidates remain in election
:) tabulate counts votes when one candidate is eliminated
:) tabulate counts votes when multiple candidates are eliminated
:) tabulate handles multiple rounds of preferences
:) print_winner prints name when someone has a majority
:) print_winner returns true when someone has a majority
:) print_winner returns false when nobody has a majority
:) print_winner returns false when leader has exactly 50% of vote
:) find_min returns minimum number of votes for candidate
:( find_min returns minimum when all candidates are tied
    find_min did not identify correct minimum
:) find_min ignores eliminated candidates
:) is_tie returns true when election is tied
:) is_tie returns false when election is not tied
:) is_tie returns false when only some of the candidates are tied
:) is_tie detects tie after some candidates have been eliminated

Here is the code:
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max voters and candidates
#define MAX_VOTERS 100
#define MAX_CANDIDATES 9

// preferences[i][j] is jth preference for voter i
int preferences[MAX_VOTERS][MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Candidates have name, vote count, eliminated status
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
    bool eliminated;
} candidate;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX_CANDIDATES];

// Numbers of voters and candidates
int voter_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name);
void tabulate(void);
bool print_winner(void);
int find_min(void);
bool is_tie(int min);
void eliminate(int min);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: runoff [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX_CANDIDATES)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX_CANDIDATES);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
        candidates[i].eliminated = false;
    }

    voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");
    if (voter_count > MAX_VOTERS)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of voters is %i\n", MAX_VOTERS);
        return 3;
    }

    // Keep querying for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            // Record vote, unless it's invalid
            if (!vote(i, j, name))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 4;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    // Keep holding runoffs until winner exists
    while (true)
    {
        // Calculate votes given remaining candidates
        tabulate();

        // Check if election has been won
        bool won = print_winner();
        if (won)
        {
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate last-place candidates
        int min = find_min();
        bool tie = is_tie(min);

        // If tie, everyone wins
        if (tie)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
            {
                if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        // Eliminate anyone with minimum number of votes
        eliminate(min);

        // Reset vote counts back to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
        {
            candidates[i].votes = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Record preference if vote is valid
bool vote(int voter, int rank, string name)
{
    int cmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        cmp = strcmp(candidates[i].name, name);
        if (cmp == 0)
        {
            preferences[voter][rank] = i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Tabulate votes for non-eliminated candidates
void tabulate(void)
{
    int cont;
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        cont = 0;
        while (candidates[preferences[i][cont]].eliminated)
        {
            cont++;
        }
        candidates[preferences[i][cont]].votes++;
    }
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election, if there is one
bool print_winner(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > (voter_count / 2))
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Return the minimum number of votes any remaining candidate has
int find_min(void)
{
    int min = candidate_count + 1;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            printf("%s eliminado\n", candidates[i].name);
        }
        if (!candidates[i].eliminated)
        {
            if (candidates[i].votes < min)
            {
                min = candidates[i].votes;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%i", min);
    return min;
}

// Return true if the election is tied between all candidates, false otherwise
bool is_tie(int min)
{
    int cont = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes > max)
        {
            max = candidates[i].votes;
        }
    }
    if (max == min)
        return true;
    return false;
}

// Eliminate the candidate (or candidates) in last place
void eliminate(int min)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[i].votes == min)
        {
            candidates[i].eliminated = true;
        }
    }
    return;
}



Do you have the input that causes the failure? Then you can easily hard-code it into a [mre] (with emphasis on the minimal part) and use a debugger to step through the code to see what really happens.

Did you try with more voters than candidates? Maybe 2 candidates and 20 voters? Does it print 10 then? I suspect that int min = candidate_count + 1; should use number of voters instead of number of candidates.

A generic approach to find min/max of a series would be to initialize with the value of first entry (candidates[0].votes) instead of some unrelated start value. Then only loop over the remaining entries. In your case, you may first need to find the first (non-eliminated) entry for that purpose.

What makes you think that it is correct? What result do you see? For which input? What test cases did you invent yourself to verify your assumptions?

A minimum test case showing the issue would be: 2 candidates and 8 voters. Number of voters must be larger than (number of candidates + 1). Then you will return wrong minimum and end in an infinite loop.

Thank you guys. I confused myself and used candidate count + 1  instead of voter_count + 1 as @Gerhardh said. How can I up vote your answer? I am new to the platform

They didn't post it as an answer, so you can't vote for it.

Questions about minor typo-style errors like this serve no lasting purpose for other readers. Just delete the question.
